# Cancel out a prompt if something equals something

Tags: javascript, html

I got this prompt that makes it change the document.title when the prompt has been submitted, but i want it to make it so that if my prompt equals something, it cancels out the prompt, how to do that?
here is my HTML and JS, also it changes the h1 text, in the snippet it wont change the stackoverflow title cause it's already pre defined.

P.S: i know it's gonna be something small i missed, but pardon me for that i'm still a beginner >_<

```js
const h1 = document.getElementById('h1');
function myFunction() {
    let mainTitle = "Enter website title..."
    let websiteTitle = prompt("What is your website title?", mainTitle)
    if(websiteTitle != null ) {
        document.title = websiteTitle;
        h1.innerText = websiteTitle;
    } else if(document.title === mainTitle) {
        websiteTitle = null;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pets.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="h1">Website Title here!</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change Website Title</button>
<script src="pets.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "if my prompt equals something, it cancels out the prompt," What does that mean?

Comment: what i meant was if my title was equal to mainTitle (in this case it's "enter website here...") then make the prompt false, and close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood what you are trying to do, but I'll leave here a snippet with the solution to the problem I think you have:

```js
const h1 = document.getElementById('h1');
function myFunction() {
    let mainTitle = "Enter website title..."
    let websiteTitle = prompt("What is your website title?", mainTitle)
    if(websiteTitle != null ) {
        document.title = websiteTitle;
        h1.innerText = websiteTitle;
    }
    if(websiteTitle === mainTitle) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pets.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="h1">Website Title here!</h1>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change Website Title</button>
<script src="pets.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you this is literally what i wanted ^_^, i didnt know  about the window reload, thanks for your solution :)

Comment: unclear how reloading the page is what you wanted..... but okay....

Answer (score 0):

I can't close a prompt yourself, the user has to do it, you may want to use an `input` and manually hide it / show it to simulate a prompt.